# List of Id's top value row Lists

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

| Student_id | mark | semester |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 50 | 2 |
| 002 | 80 | 2 |
| 001 | 52 | 3 |
| 002 | 78 | 3 |

I want a query to get each student_id
's highest mark row.

excepted output :

| Student_id | mark | semester |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | 80 | 2 |
| 001 | 52 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `GROUP BY Student_id` to be able to retrieve the max mark.

```sql
SELECT Student_id, MAX(mark) as mark, semester FROM grades GROUP BY student_id
```

If you want to sort the marks in descending order, add `ORDER BY mark DESC` to the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Partition the data and rank them  in  descending order , extract result which having rank 1 its in sqlserver

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ROLL,MARK,rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ROLL ORDER BY MARK desc)[rank],SEM    FROM #NEW)
select roll,mark,sem from cte where rank=1 
--sqlserver
```